# Length function and type classes in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

```
media :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
media [] = 0
media lst = (head lst) + media (tail lst)
```

This is a working function that goes through a number list and sum each element with the following element.

```
media2 :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
media2 str = (media str) / (length str)
```

This second function was supposed to get that sum and divide it by the length of the list, thus getting the arithmetic mean of the list. BUT the compiler returns me this

```
src/Main.hs@6:29-6:39Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
from the context (Num a)
bound by the type signature for media2 :: Num a => [a] -> a
at /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/32614/src.207/Main.hs:6:1-39
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by
the type signature for media2 :: Num a => [a] -> a
at /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/32614/src.207/Main.hs:6:1
In the return type of a call of `length'
In the second argument of `(/)', namely `(length str)'
In the expression: (media str) / (length str)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, can someone please tell me?

Comment: It says `media str` has type `a`, and `length str` has type `Int`, and you cannot divide one by the other because it cannot prove that `a` is actually `Int`.

Comment: Haskell already has a function to do what `media` does; it's called `sum`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`length`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=length) function always returns an `Int`, so you are trying to divide a `(Num a) => a` by an `Int`. The [`fromIntegral`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers) function will convert the `Int` into any `Num` type:

```
media2 :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
media2 str = (media str) / (fromIntegral $ length str)
```

**EDIT**

Just a couple of words about some insightful comments:

1. Your `media` function is just the Prelude's `sum`.
2. I'll assume you don't always want an `Integral` average, so I've changed the constraint on `media2` to be `Fractional` instead of `Num`. This is because `/` has the type `(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a`. Alternatively, you could use

   ```
   media2 :: (Integral a) => [a] -> a
   media2 str = (media str) `div` (fromIntegral $ length str)
   ```

   but you'll always get an integral average, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The nonintuitive bit for people coming from other languages is that `/` is not overloaded to work on `Int`s in `Haskell`. You either have to explicitly use integer division (using `quot` or `div`) or convert the numerator and denominator to something that implements `Fractional`.

Comment: The type for `media2` should be `Fractional a => [a] -> a`. `Num a` is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`genericLength`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3agenericLength) from `Data.List`:

> The genericLength function is an overloaded version of length. In particular, instead of returning an Int, it returns any type which is an instance of Num. It is, however, less efficient than length.

It's type signature is

```
genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i
```

Usage:

```
import Data.List

media2 :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
media2 str = (media str) / (genericLength str)
```